# array without repetitions, algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have to write function that returns given array sorted and  without repetitions.

I came up with solution like that:

```
 public static String [] no_repeats(String [] a)
    {
        Arrays.sort(a);

        ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i =1; i < a.length; i++)
                   if(a[i].compareTo(a[i-1]) != 0)
                       ret.add(a[i]);

        return  ret.toArray(ret.toArray(new String[0]));
    }
```

I'm wondering if there is better (faster) solution for my problem?
Collections  like eg. Set are not allowed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're required to sort anyway, I think this would be a good way to do it.  The algorithm simply keeps track of the last value added to make certain not to add a duplicate.

```
public static String[] no_repeats(String[] a) {
    
    Arrays.sort(a);
    
    ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    String lastAdded = "";
    for (String str : a) {
        if (!str.equals(lastAdded)) {
            ret.add(str);
        }
        lastAdded = str;
    }
    return ret.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Of course, you could write your own minimal hash implementation to speed up lookups in a home grown hash set.  In that case, sorting **after** you've skipped duplicate elements would be the way to go since hash based lookups, unlike `List.contains()` calls, are very efficient. And then you would be sorting on fewer items.

Here is how it might look with your own set implementation to speed up the process.

- set.add() returns false if the element is already there.
- so when it returns true, it must be the first time encountered so add it to the list.
- now sort a smaller list.
- and return the array.

```
public static String[] no_repeats(String[] a) {
    
    MiniHashSet<String> set = new MiniHashSet<>();
    
    ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (String str : a) {
        if (set.add(str)) {
            ret.add(str);
        }
    }
    
    Collections.sort(ret);
    return ret.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

This is a simple implementation that just has an add and contains method to speed up the lookup process.  The hash table size is rather large to reduce the chances of a collision.

- this class uses the hashCode of the object to obtain the proper `bucket` to place a list.
- Each list may hold what ever items hash to that bucket.
  -The returned bucket will either be the existing list for that index into the array or an new list where none previously existed.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
class MiniHashSet<T> {
    int size = 10_000;
    
    List<T>[] data = new ArrayList[size];
    
    public boolean add(T val) {
        List<T> b = getBucket(val);
        if (!b.contains(val)) {
            b.add(val);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public boolean contains(T val) {
        List<T> b = getBucket(val);
        return b.contains(val);
    }
    
    private List<T> getBucket(T val) {
        int i = val.hashCode() % size;
        List<T> b = data[i];
        if (b == null) {
            b = new ArrayList<>();
            data[i] = b;
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Although this is quite a bit of extra work, this solution is significantly better than the first one I offered because the lookup is efficient and the sort may now happen after the duplicates have been removed.

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be solved elegantly by using streams:

```
public static String[] no_repeats(String[] a) {
    return Arrays.stream(a)
            .distinct()
            .sorted()
            .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The point of this task is to independently write solution that reduces in good way repetition

Answer (score 2):

Sort it, then check if the elements are equal(if they are, then they are together)

```
    public static String[] no_repeats(String[] a)
    {
        Arrays.sort(a);
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add(a[0]);
        for(int i = 1;i<a.length;i++) {
            if(!a[i].equals(a[i - 1])) {
                al.add(a[i]);
            }
        }

        return  al.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```